# counting checked checkboxes using jquery (keeps returning 0)

Tags: jquery

I would like to create an alert once too many check boxes have been checked.

Please see the setup here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wDbej/2/

At the moment - the alert keep returning 0 - rather than counting the checkboxes...

Any suggestions would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wDbej/6/ - move your variable inside the click function.  The way you had it initialized the variable, but didn't update the value on clicking the box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the length calculation *inside* the event handler, otherwise it's just going to be calculated once in the start and be 0 constantly.